# Application running in background

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

How can I write C# application using Visual Studio 2010 that runs in background? By this I mean that it does not run in console or show a Form. Which type of project should I use?

Comment: Just don't create a form in your Main() method.

Comment: For what it's worth, you need to carefully consider choosing to use a Windows Service. It can be very useful (nay, ideal) for certain tasks, but far too many users try to use a Service where it *isn't* a good idea. There are several important limitations as compared to a standard desktop application, chief among them is that **a Windows Service can't have any type of user interface**, which includes something as simple as showing a message box. (At least, it can't in Windows Vista or later; it can in earlier versions, but it *shouldn't*.) It's not clear from your question if you require this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a windows service template

Add a new project of type 'Windows->Windows Service'.

Here is a [walkthrough](http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Architecture/Writing-a-Managed-Windows-Service-with-C/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a **Windows** project that doesn't show any forms, or you can use a [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412.aspx) project.

Comment: +1 I actually had to use the Windows project option because my employer denied my request for the paid version of Visual Studio, and the ability to create a Windows Service is not available in the free version.  This solution worked like a charm, though.